# What is the regex example for: a string should not contain any sequence of characters immediately followed by the same sequence?

Tags: java, regex

In my program I had a regex which ensures an input string has at least one alpha and one numeric character and the length is in between 2 to 10.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]{2,10}$");
```

Per new requirement, the string also should not contain any sequence of characters immediately followed by the same sequence. I searched a lot but could not figure out. Can you please help? Or point me to any URL/ documentation?

---

Thanks a lot for the responses.

Requirement: String must not contain any sequence of characters immediately followed by the same sequence.

I think the requirement is not clear.

I am not sure if “12aardvark” is valid, because -
1. has repeating “a”. It is same with string “11abcdefg”.
2. has repeating “ar”
3. but “ar” is not immediately followed by the same sequence. There is “dv” in between.

I think, the string “12ardvark” and “12aardvark” should not pass the validation because it has repeating character sequence: “ar”, though it not immediately followed by the same sequence.

"fofo123" or "ab1212" should not pass for sure because "fo" (just 2 chars) is immediately followed by the same sequence.

What are your assumptions of the requirement?

Comment: Define "sequence of characters followed by the same sequence of characters". Is `aardvark` excluded because it contains the character `a` twice in a row?

Comment: @Li-aung Yip:Point to notice that, input data must have at least one alpha and one number according to OP.

Comment: @Cylian: sure. My question could be rephrased as: "is `11abcdefg` excluded because it contains `1` twice in a row?"

Answer (score 7):

[A monolithic regex is not the answer to every string-validation problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298776/regular-expression-for-validating-username/10300457#10300457)

It's far more readable to use basic string functions and multiple, smaller regexes. (Why try to check the length of a string using regex when `length(pwd)` will do the same thing?)

Here's some Python code that should translate well to Java:

```
import re
def validate_password(pwd):
    # return true if valid or false is invalid.

    if ( len(pwd) < 2 or len(pwd) > 10 ):
        print "Password %s : Failed length requirement" % pwd
        return False
    if ( re.search(r"\d", pwd) == None ):
        print "Password %s : must contain at least one number" % pwd
        return False     
    if ( re.search(r"[a-zA-Z]", pwd) == None ):
        print "Password %s : must contain at least one alphabetical character" % pwd
        return False
    if ( re.search(r"(...+)\1", pwd) != None ):
        print "Password %s : must not contain any repeating substrings of three characters or more" % pwd
        return False

    print "Password %s is OK" % pwd
    return True

test_pwds = [ "1", "123", "aardvark", "12ardvark", "12aardvark", "foofoofoo1" ]

for pwd in test_pwds:
    validate_password (pwd)
```

Test output:

```
Password 1 : Failed length requirement
Password 123 : must contain at least one alphabetical character
Password aardvark : must contain at least one number
Password 12ardvark is OK
Password 12aardvark is OK
Password foofoofoo1 : must not contain any repeating substrings of three characters or more
```

Validating the input using a series of small tests, instead of one giant test, has several benefits:

1. It's easier to understand.
2. It's easier to debug.
3. It's easier to maintain in the future. (Imagine your boss adds another requirement, that at least two symbols must appear in the password.)
4. You can tell the user *what criteria* their password failed on, instead of some generic message like "Your password must meet `giant list of criteria`".